# What has the eye surgeon Dr. Solomon Eddie written on his shirt?

Tags: costume, minority-report

In *Minority Report*, once John Anderton gets his eyes replaced by Dr. Solomon Eddie we can see a writing on the doc's wife-beater:

[image]

There are clearly six letters and an arrow but I can't make any sense out of it. Do the letters mean anything?

Comment: Looks like "anster" written upside down.  Apart from being a type of cheese, I'm not finding much on what "anster" might mean, though.

Comment: I always thought this is a K and the words is "Prankster".

Comment: Interesting catch, I never noticed before. I can't find any meaningful anagrams with these letters and now I wonder why this random word is there...

Comment: Since Peter Stormare is [Swedish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Stormare), this might be *TJÄNSTER*, which [means](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/swedish-english/tj%C3%A4nster) "services". It kind of would make sense (with the arrow showing that Eddie will service you), and it seems like the *A* has an [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)).

Comment: I like your thinking @AnneDaunted, especially since I think that might be the bottom of a "J" peeking out from his pants "above" the "A"

Comment: Based on reviewing the scene, it does look like TJÄNSTER as @AnneDaunted stated, but there is another word on his right side that ends in GER (probably 3 letters before that). Since there are arrows with both words, maybe it was used so the actor would remember services (kitchen) was on the left and something (bathroom) was on the right